# Interpreting LRT output

Tags: interpretation, likelihood-ratio

I am comparing the fit of two models:

```
> lrtest(fullmodel,reducedmodel)
Likelihood ratio test

Model 1: MM ~ x * y + (1 | Replicate)
Model 2: MM ~ x * y
  #Df LogLik Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)    
1   8 357.35                         
2   7 368.40 -1 22.095  2.595e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

So from looking at the output the models are significant. How do I tell what model is best - do you use the LogLik value? Do I pick the one with the lowest LogLik value (e.g. in this case Model 2 has the lowest LogLik so that is the best model)?

Answer (score 1):

The *models* are not significant. Read *There is a significant difference in the two compared models (in log likelihoods)*. In this particular implementation it appears that you want to maximize the `LogLik`, so in your case Model 2 (without random effects) is the more parsimonious model.

Comment: I am confused as to how they're aren't different given the P value is less than 0.05? If they aren't different then wouldn't the p value be above 0.05

Comment: @user255144 They are different. My statement was referring to the fact that there is a statistical difference between the models, however this does not guarantee that any of the models is significant on their own. There is a difference.

Comment: @user2974951 deleting my earlier comment, not knowing what "Model B" entails, it could be anything, including a model that is "worse" than null. So I agree that we can't borrow the interpretation of a significant LRT as a global test, in general.